# ElasticSearch terms and cardinality performance with high cardinality fields

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, query-performance, nosql

## TL;DR

My ElasticSearch query takes forever compared to the same query on SQL Server.
Am I doing something wrong?  Is there any way to boost my query's performance?
**Is it just one of those things RDBMS does better than NoSQL?**

## Premise

Let's say I have a business that takes orders and delivers requested items.

- I would like to know the average amount of unique items per order.
- My orders data is arranged per item ordered - each order has one or more records containing Order ID, Item ID and more.
- I have a one node setup for development purposes
- The results (performance-wise) are the same whether I have 4 GB heap space (on a 12 GB machine) or 16 GB heap space (on a 32 GB machine)
- The index has billions of records, but the query filters it to about 300,000 records
- The Order and Item ID's are of type *keyword* (textual by nature) and I have no way to change that.
- In this particular case, the average unique item count is 1.65  - with many orders containing only one unique item, others contain 2 and a few contain up to 25 unique items.

## The Problem

Using ElasticSearch, I would have to use *Terms Aggregation* to group documents by order ID, *Cardinality Aggregation* to get unique item count, and *Average Bucket* aggregation to get the average item count per order.

This takes about 23 seconds on both my setups. Same query takes less than 2 seconds with the same dataset on SQL Server.

## Additional Information

### ElasticSearch Query

```
{
   "size":0,
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "filter":[
            {
               ...
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "aggs":{
      "OrdersBucket":{
         "terms":{
            "field":"orderID",
            "execution_hint":"global_ordinals_hash",
            "size":10000000
         },
         "aggs":{
            "UniqueItems":{
               "cardinality":{
                  "field":"itemID"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "AverageItemCount":{
         "avg_bucket":{
            "buckets_path":"OrdersBucket>UniqueItems"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

At first my query generated *OutOfMemoryException* which brought my server down.
Issuing the same request on my higher ram setup yielded the following circuit breaker:

> ```
> [request] Data too large, data for [<reused_arrays>] would be
> [14383258184/13.3gb], which is larger than the limit of
> [10287002419/9.5gb]
> ```

ElasticSearch github has several (currently) open issues on this matter:

[Cardinality aggregation should not reserve a fixed amount of memory per bucket #15892](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/15892)

[global_ordinals execution mode for the terms aggregation has an adversarially impact on children aggregations that expect dense buckets #24788](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/24788)

[Heap Explosion on even small cardinality queries in ES 5.3.1 / Kibana 5.3.1 #24359](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/24359)

All of which led me to use execution hint "global_ordinals_hash" which allowed the query to complete successfully (albeit taking it's time..)

### Analogous SQL Query

```
SELECT AVG(CAST(uniqueCount.amount AS FLOAT)) FROM 
(   SELECT o.OrderID, COUNT(DISTINCT o.ItemID) AS amount 
    FROM Orders o
    WHERE ...
    GROUP BY o.OrderID 
) uniqueCount
```

And this, as I've said, is very very fast.

### orderID field mapping

```
{
   "orderID":{
      "full_name":"orderID",
      "mapping":{
         "orderID":{
            "type":"keyword",
            "boost":1,
            "index":true,
            "store":false,
            "doc_values":true,
            "term_vector":"no",
            "norms":false,
            "index_options":"docs",
            "eager_global_ordinals":true,
            "similarity":"BM25",
            "fields":{
               "autocomplete":{
                  "type":"text",
                  "boost":1,
                  "index":true,
                  "store":false,
                  "doc_values":false,
                  "term_vector":"no",
                  "norms":true,
                  "index_options":"positions",
                  "eager_global_ordinals":false,
                  "similarity":"BM25",
                  "analyzer":"autocomplete",
                  "search_analyzer":"standard",
                  "search_quote_analyzer":"standard",
                  "include_in_all":true,
                  "position_increment_gap":-1,
                  "fielddata":false
               }
            },
            "null_value":null,
            "include_in_all":true,
            "ignore_above":2147483647,
            "normalizer":null
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I have set *eager_global_ordinals* trying to boost performance, but to no avail.

### Sample Document

```
{
            "_index": "81cec0acbca6423aa3c2feed5dbccd98",
            "_type": "order",
            "_id": "AVwpLZ7GK9DJVcpvrzss",
            "_score": 0,
            "_source": {
        ...
               "orderID": "904044A",
               "itemID": "23KN",
        ...
            }
}
```

Irrelevant fields removed for brevity and undisclosable content

### Sample Output

```
{
   "OrdersBucket":{
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
      "sum_other_doc_count":0,
      "buckets":[
         {
            "key":"910117A",
            "doc_count":16,
            "UniqueItems":{
               "value":16
            }
         },
         {
            "key":"910966A",
            "doc_count":16,
            "UniqueItems":{
               "value":16
            }
         },
        ...
         {
            "key":"912815A",
            "doc_count":1,
            "UniqueItems":{
               "value":1
            }
         },
         {
            "key":"912816A",
            "doc_count":1,
            "UniqueItems":{
               "value":1
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "AverageItemCount":{
      "value":1.3975020363833832
   }
}
```

**Any help will be much appreciated :)**

Comment: Can you please share a sample document and a sample output. That would be very helpful

Comment: Edited those into the question. Though I don't see how they help much (except making the question more TL;DR worthy ;) )

Comment: Is this possible for you to change the structure of your index. It is generally advisable to index your data in a way that is easy to query. and Since ES is a no sql database, we should better keep data in an un-normalized form.

Comment: Hi @Richa, this is actually un-normalized form... how would you un-normalize it further? Also, this question can easily be generalized - this pattern of cardinality aggregation within terms aggregation and then a pipeline aggregation isn't specific to my structure (which as far as I can see is the most un-normalized as it gets). I am currently testing the effect of making that field numeric, but the question remains - is this a sort of thing for RDBMS only or are there any measures I can take to keep using ES for this kind of work?

Comment: Fields removed for brevity include date, client id, and such.  In a normalized form, they won't exist on item level, but on order level only.

Comment: I was thinking of keeping one record per order with List of items in a nested type with itemId and its count.

Comment: That's actually normalizing the data. Currently I cannot do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently SQL Server does a good job at caching those results.
**Further investigation showed initial query to be taking the same time as with ElasticSearch.**

I will look into why those results are not cached properly via ElasticSearch.

I also managed to convert the order ID to an integer, which dramatically enhanced performance (though same performance gain with SQL Server as well).

Also, [as advised by Mark Harwood on the Elastic Forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/terms-aggregation-cardinality-aggregation-performance/87365), specifying *precision_threshold* on the cardinality aggregation lowered memory consumption a lot!

So the answer is that for this particular kind of query, ES performs at least as well as SQL Server.